# can I use lists as positions for a stepper motor to rotate to in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So I want to know if its possible for me to use list/array and set each element to a position and make the stepper motor rotate to that element position?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible to use list/array here, but the key point is what is your requirement and how your code works out, because there are many types of stepper motors and different use cases for controlling the position, for example, if there are position sensors? if the initial position matters? unidirectional? error tolerance?